# Having trouble populating textboxes from a combo box selection

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I am trying to have the item selected from the combo box (Site PSI) auto-populate all the textboxes to the right. I have scoured the web and there is some data source selections and auotocomplete sections but they are not working. I have tried several steps that were resolved with a similar issue on this website but it is not working. Here is my code. the combobox is called cmbSitePSI and the text boxes txtSiteName, txtSiteLName, etc...I was able to autopopulate them from a grid but I am not using a grid. Please help, thank you so much in advance.

[image]

```
        con.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(@"Select * from Site order by SitePSI", con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
  
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select SiteName, SiteLongName, SiteAddress1, SiteAddress2, SiteAddress3, SiteCity, SiteState, SiteZipCode, SiteCountry, " +
            "SiteOperationsRegion from Site where SitePSI = '" + cmbSitePSI.Text + "'", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SitePSI", int.Parse(cmbSitePSI.Text));
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        dt1.Load(dr);
```

**UPDATE**

I have tried using this method but I have not been successful. I get squiggilies on these lines string sSiteName = r.GetString("SiteName");

```
  private void CmbSitePSI_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter da2 = new SqlDataAdapter(@"Select * from Site where SitePSI = '" + cmbSitePSI + "'", con);

        string constring = "Data Source=*********;Initial Catalog=DIETS;Integrated Security=True";
        string Query = "Select * from Site where SitePSI = '" + cmbSitePSI.Text + "' ;";
        SqlConnection condata = new SqlConnection(constring);
        SqlCommand cmddata = new SqlCommand(Query, condata);
        SqlDataReader r;

        try
        {
            condata.Open();
            r = cmddata.ExecuteReader();

            while (r.Read())
            {
                string sSiteName = r.GetString("SiteName");
                string sSiteLongName = r.GetString("SiteLongName");
                txtSiteName.Text = sSiteName;
                txtSiteLName.Text = sSiteLongName;

            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

Comment: This looks like it could be Windows Forms (`winforms` tag), but it's hard to tell. Please [edit] your question to include the tag for the UI technology you're working with.

Comment: As i understand, your combobox shows elements. If you select one, the textboxes should show the information of the selected item. Then use `SelectedIndexChanged` event.

Comment: @SebastianSiemens, never used an event before. You have an example? Do I do this for every textbox? When I select the combo box and go to events and select the drop down next to selectedindexchange there are only two  options Form1_load and btnStaffSite_Click

Comment: @AnthonyMullins Here is an example: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindexchanged?view=net-5.0 Use it for the Combobox. If the user select an item in the combobox this event is triggered.

Comment: @SebastianSiemens which one, there are many examples? Thank you for your time sir!

Comment: @AnthonyMullins You can create this event easy if you doubleclick on the combobox in your form. if there is an event already the doubleklick will show you the event in code.

Comment: @AnthonyMullins I think i misunderstand your question. If you select an item in the combobox, the sqlcommand should be triggered. so the part where you execute your sqlcommand should be within your selectedindexchanged event. After getting the values from database you can simply set each value for the texboxes. Or you could bind them to a property where you store the database object.

Comment: @SebastianSiemens yeah it is not working. I have also watched another video doing it a different way, which was just him creating a table in visual studio as opposed to one existing in a sql server already. No luck.